# eclipse c/c++ project, GCC compiling G++ code

Tags: eclipse, gcc, g++, stm32

i work with system workbench 4 stm32 (eclipse).
there i have a mixed C/C++ project where C++ files include C (never a problem) and C files include C++ files (big trouble).

i have clearly always defined .cpp/.hpp for c++ files and .c/.h for c files. also, any C file has declaired if __cpluplus extern "C".

but a GCC compilation, then leading to a c++ header (.hpp) then would compile with GCC and tell my "unknown type class"... but as far as i know this shouldnt happen since its declaired c++ (.hpp)

how can i work with this project:

option A: 
somehow remove the GCC compiler of the project and work with G++ only

Question A1: how do you remove a compiler from the project? 
Question A2: g++ is quite more picky and wont compile all, since i use freertos for example which does a lot of typecasting that my compiler doesent like at all

option B:
having a strict top-town architecture, where c++ is allowed to include c files but not the other way around (also not a good option since i use the stm32 hal layer that needs to make callbacks/isr handlings (c to then my code which is c++)

NO OPTION: 
using gcc only

how do you solve such things?
thanks a lot
gonna go crazy over this :-)

Comment: Any source file that `#include`s a C++ header *is not a C source file*,
it is a C++ source file. (Unless the C++ header,
and any files that *it* includes, happen to contain only C code. I.e it's not really a C++ header; it's really a C header.)
So it is quite pointless to call such a source file `foo.c`. It
can only be compiled by a C++ compiler: so call it `foo.cpp`.

Comment: hi mike. thanks for your input. then, basically, when i have a strict top-down arcitecture (.cpp files include .h files but .c are not allowed to include .hpp) all my code is basically c++ code that will be completely compiled as c++?

what i dont understand, why do i have to have a g++ and a gcc compiler within my eclipse project? since from the build output, gcc is used for .c and g++ is used for .cpp when i just could use g++ for all files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a GCC compilation, then leading to a c++ header (.hpp) then would
>   compile with GCC and tell my "unknown type class"... but as far as i
>   know this shouldnt happen since its declaired c++ (.hpp)

You can include **anything** in a `.c` or `.cpp` file, it will be compiled as a part of the including file, using the same language, as if it were a part of it. Look at the Qt headers for an example, they are named like `QWidget`, `QString`, not having an extension at all. They in turn include `qwidget.h` and `qstring.h`, which are not valid C files, with lots of classes defined in them. I'm doing this in a project I'm working on right now:

```
uint8_t foo[] = {
#include "bar.txt"
};
```

where `bar.txt` is just a list of numbers. The compiler doesn't mind the extension, or that it's not a valid C or C++ file on it's own.

You can use `#ifdef __cplusplus` to mask constructs in your C++ headers that are not compatible with C, for example

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
int foo(int);
int foo(int, int);
class example {
public:
    example(int);
    int field;
};
extern "C" {
#endif
int bar(int);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`foo()` is overloaded, so it's not usable in C, and cannot go into the `extern "C"` block, therefore it's declared inside `#ifdef __cplusplus` to hide it from `gcc`. The class declaration is likewise protected. `bar()` can be defined in a `.cpp` file, then it can be called from C code, and it can work with any C++ construct, like classes, overloaded functions, etc.